# Error installing service, cant access/edit security log?

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, services, event-log

I'm trying to install a proprietary service on a client machine and I continue to run into the same issue [image: command]

I've checked all the user permissions even though I'm on an admin account. I also checked session permissions in the registry and made sure all appropriate permissions were assigned.

This computer has been wiped before performing this operation, so I also removed any users labeled with an ?S-(code) and their inherited permissions. But I still cannot get this service to install. It is the first time I've run into this issue. This is on windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I right clicked and ran as admin.....wasn't thinking of something that simple

-0-